# What AB testing can handle websites that contain dynamic pages

Tags: ab-testing, dynamic-pages

I want to perform A/B testing and we have a lot of dynamic pages on our website. Is there any best A/B testing tool that can handle this situation? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Any A/B testing tool, including the free ones, are meant to work with dymanic pages. The world would be a sad place if all you could test were one static page against another.